# Run a code in Glue Jobs, which materializes data in s3 but does not appear in the Athena select

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I run code in Glue Jobs, it materializes data in s3 but it does not appear in the Athena select.

This Glue Job consists of changing a table in the Data Mesh SOR layer, which had a partition type (by dat_cria_prpt_nego) and now 3 new columns were generated, with them being year, month and day to be the 3 partition columns.

The entire schema was changed, via the governance team, the table has the partitioning structure as per prints, but when it runs successfully, it does not update the data in Athena. I tested applying a method to force the MSCK REPAIR TABLE command to run via code, but it runs the job and the data does not appear. When I run this command manually in Athena, it gives the print message:

> Partitions not in metastore:

As I researched is not updated in the Glue Catalog, but I tried some update options and it didn't work. Is there an example on the web that I can look at?

Just letting you know, I updated my polices and rules to be able to run the test methods

```
import sys
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import boto3


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "S3_OUTPUT_PATH", "GLUE_TABLE_NAME", "GLUE_CONNECTION_NAME", "GLUE_TABLE_CATALOG", "GLUE_DATA_CATALOG", "S3_OUTPUT_BUCKE_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)


def load_partitions(args):
    athena = boto3.client("athena")

    print("Loading partitions...")

    try:

        athena.start_query_execution(

            QueryString=f'MSCK REPAIR TABLE '

                        f'{args["GLUE_TABLE_CATALOG"]};',

            QueryExecutionContext={"Database": args["GLUE_DATA_CATALOG"]},

            ResultConfiguration={

                "OutputLocation":

                    f's3://{args["S3_OUTPUT_BUCKE_NAME"]}/'}

        )

    except Exception as error:

        print(error)

        raise error

    else:

        print("Partitions loaded!")


SQLServertable = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="sqlserver",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": args["GLUE_TABLE_NAME"],
        "connectionName": args["GLUE_CONNECTION_NAME"],
    },
    transformation_ctx="SQLServertable",
)

SQLServerTablePropostas = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="sqlserver",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "TBCB7090_PRPT_NEGO",
        "connectionName": args["GLUE_CONNECTION_NAME"],
    },
    transformation_ctx="SQLServertable",
)

# Join com tabela de propostas pra pegar a data de criacao da proposta
SqlServerTableJoin = Join.apply(SQLServertable, SQLServerTablePropostas, 'NUM_PRPT_NEGO', 'NUM_PRPT_NEGO').drop_fields(
    ['COD_TIPO_FORL_DGTL', 'COD_ORIG_PRPT_NEGO', 'COD_CANA_DTBC', 'IND_LOGN_ATIV', 'NOM_SERV_ALTE_PRPT',
     'HOR_CRIA_PRPT', 'COD_FAMI_PROD', 'COD_SITU_PRPT'])


# Adicionar colunas de ano, mêss e dia
SqlServerTableJoin.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")
SqlServerTableJoin = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *,
           year(DAT_CRIA_PRPT) as year,
           month(DAT_CRIA_PRPT) as month,
           dayofmonth(DAT_CRIA_PRPT) as day
    FROM temp_view
""")

SqlServerTableJoin = DynamicFrame.fromDF(SqlServerTableJoin, glueContext, "nested")

# Script generated Schema
ChangeSchema = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=SqlServerTableJoin,
    mappings=[
        ("NUM_PRPT_NEGO", "decimal", "num_prpt_nego", "bigint"),
        ("DAC10", "char", "dac10", "string"),
        ("TPEMPRES", "char", "tpempres", "string"),
        ("CODBANCO", "char", "codbanco", "string"),
        ("AGENCIA", "char", "agencia", "string"),
        ("CONTA", "char", "conta", "string"),
        ("COD_REGI_COML_PLAT", "char", "cod_regi_coml_plat", "string"),
        ("IND_CONF_RSPL_PRPT", "char", "ind_conf_rspl_prpt", "string"),
        ("DAT_CONF_RSPL_PRPT", "timestamp", "dat_conf_rspl_prpt", "timestamp"),
        ("NUM_CLAU_PRPT", "decimal", "num_clau_prpt", "bigint"),
        ("CODGER", "char", "codger", "string"),
        ("SEGCLI", "char", "segcli", "string"),
        ("AGEPLAT", "char", "ageplat", "string"),
        ("NUM_FUNL_COLA_COGL_RSPL_CONF", "char", "num_funl_cola_cogl_rspl_conf", "string"),
        ("NUM_FUNL_COLA_COGL_RSPL_CADT", "char", "num_funl_cola_cogl_rspl_cadt", "string"),
        ("NUM_FUNL_COLA_COGL_RSPL_CNQS", "char", "num_funl_cola_cogl_rspl_cnqs", "string"),
        ("IND_NECE_VISI_FISI_GERT", "char", "ind_nece_visi_fisi_gert", "string"),
        ("DAT_ASSI_PACC", "timestamp", "dat_assi_pacc", "timestamp"),
        ("COD_CATE_CONT", "char", "cod_cate_cont", "string"),
        ("NUM_AGEN_ESND", "char", "num_agen_esnd", "string"),
        ("DAT_RESE_NUM_CONT", "timestamp", "dat_rese_num_cont", "timestamp"),
        ("NOM_SGTO_PROP", "varchar", "nom_sgto_prop", "string"),
        ("DAT_CRIA_PRPT", "timestamp", "dat_cria_prpt", "date"),
        ("year", "int", "year", "int"),
        ("month", "int", "month", "int"),
        ("day", "int", "day", "int"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ChangeSchema",
)

# Script generated S3 bucket
glueContext.purge_s3_path(args["S3_OUTPUT_PATH"], {"retentionPeriod": 0})

# Aplicar pilar de particionamento
S3bucket = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ChangeSchema,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={
        "path": args["S3_OUTPUT_PATH"],
        "partitionKeys": ["year", "month", "day"],
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket",
)



load_partitions(args)

job.commit()
```

I tried the code above, and I hope a solution for the data appears in Athena's `select* from`.